# Do we have a canonical WP_DEBUG post?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've edited the title of the Q [WordPress is giving errors after activating WP_DEBUG](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/119998) to something that I think is a potential Google search query.
It was `WordPress Error Need Help`.

I've just noticed a close vote. Yes, of course it's *too localized*, but seems a good opportunity to make a canonical Q&A out of it.

Or is there a duplicate where we can link? I'm not aware of one. Or maybe we should wait for another one to do this, as editing the content is not an option.

Comment: This one: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-do-you-debug-plugins?

Comment: Oh, it doesn't appear in the first pages of the [frequent] list... I've upvoted many of the posts, must have been two ages ago.

Comment: Damn, you're [bloody fast](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/what-type-of-machine-is-toscho), I bet it's some mega-popup-message-system-diamond-only-live-warnings-thing that you have :)

Comment: Simple: go to tag `debug` and [sort by votes](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debug?sort=votes&pageSize=50). First match.

Comment: Kool, now let's Meta makes its effect on that Q.

Comment: FYI mods just get meta Qs notifications in inbox :)

Answer (score 1):

That question *is* too localized, and IMHO isn't a good candidate for appropriating as a "definitive" debug question/answer.

I would recommend writing your own question: "What are the steps to debug WordPress problems?", and then adding your own, definitive answer.

Comment: Yes, that's a good move, duly noted. IMHO, it *was* too localized until a generic title was given. . . When one is around for some time s/he can tell "oh, I *suspect* Chip voted to close this Q", :)

Comment: The **Title** was updated, but the **question content** was *not* updated. Thus, the premise of the question remained *too localized*. And yes: I close-vote often. We have a defined scope and site mechanics - including community moderation - for good reason. ;)

Comment: One has to be really inspired to change that content without defacing the OP. Anyway, I suppose that pinpointing the post here in Meta should have the community moderation effect necessary to close it or leave it.